# php - date function return wrong day name

Tags: php

I'm using this code for getting the name of tomorrow day :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
$Tomorrow = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
echo date('l', $Tomorrow);
```

I set date time , it's 10 am in iran and tomorrow is Wednesday but the return day of this function is Thursday

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing formatted date ($Tomorrow) as a second parameter here:

```
date('l', $Tomorrow);
```

but there must be timestamp.

This should work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('l');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo $datetime->format('l');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in different ways:

```
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
1) $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
   echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

2) $datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
   $datetime->modify('+1 day');
   echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

3) $datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
   $datetime->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
   echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy :-

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
echo date('l', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

For more about [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Only two line of code can do it !

Try this:

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo date('l', strtotime($datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
// Or
// echo $datetime->format('l');
// outputs: Wednesday
```